# How to synchornize a Spring HttpMessageWriter?

Tags: spring-webflux

I need to access the output of a Spring `HttpMessageWriter<?>` inside the implementation of a  an external lib interface which is synchronized.

I'm trying to write a Swagger `ModelConverter` which would use the `FormattingConversionService` and registered `HttpMessageWriter` to return the "written" values for enum entries.

Has anyone managed to "synchronize" a `HttpMessageWriter`? Which `ReactiveHttpOutputMessage` implementation do you use for that?